# How to tell whether a variable is null or undefined in php

Tags: php

Is there a **single** function that can be created to tell whether a variable is NULL or undefined in PHP?  I will pass the variable to the function (by reference if needed) but I won't know the name of the variable until runtime.

`isset()` and `is_null()` do not distinguish between NULL and undefined.
`array_key_exists` requires you to know the name of the variable as you're writing your code.
And I haven't found a way to determine the name of a variable without defining it.

#### Edit

I've also realized that passing a variable by reference automatically defines it.

#### Elaboration

Through the collection of these answers and comments I've determined that the short answer to my question is "No". Thank you for all the input.

Here are some details on why I needed this:

I've created a PHP function called `LoadQuery()` that pulls a particular SQL query from an array of queries and then prepares it for submission to MySQL. Most-importantly I scan the query for variables (like `$UserID`) that I then replace with their values from the current scope.  In creating this function I needed a way to determine if a variable had been declared, and was NULL, empty, or had a value.  This is why I may not know the name of the given variable until runtime.

Comment: Are you saying you need to know whether a variable is one or the other?

Comment: Yes. I need to know **which** it is.  Is it NULL or is it undefined.

Comment: One could play _extremely_ dirty tricks with `get_last_error` and the like, but that would just be a theoretical exercise, not something I'd ever like to see in code. I will say that it smells like a very weird thing to do, and possibly this can be better handled on another level / with another design. Could you give us some example how you would use this code?

Comment: I considered trying to capture that `undefined variable` error as a last resort. Not a bad idea.

Comment: @Wrikken I was thinking the same thing, see my answer below

Comment: @Phil: I was thinking even dirtier, with `get_last_error` mashed with `debug_backtrace`.... But still, this _should not be needed_. There's a design flaw here, unless it's a purely academic question, and we should explore _that_

Comment: @Wrikken Agreed, I'd like to see how this is intended to be used

Comment: @Phil, I've added some context above.

Comment: `array_key_exists requires you to know the name of the variable as you're writing your code.` I'm not sure that it is true...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially the answer is no. There is not a single function you can create that will tell whether a runtime variable is null or is undefined. (by 'runtime variable' I mean a variable who's name you don't yet know at the time of coding. See **Elaboration** in the question above).

**Relevant Observations:**

- There's no way to retrieve the name of a variable at runtime without giving it a value and hence declaring it.
- If you pass a variable by reference, instead of by value, you're automatically declaring it. So then in the function you can't go back and determine whether it was declared before you passed it.
- You can use `array_key_exists('variable_name', $GLOBALS)` as @zzzzBov stated, to see if a variable has been declared, but *only* if you know the name of the variable at coding time.

**Possible 'Dirty' Solutions**

- As @Phil (and @zzzzBov) explained you could use a messy trick of capturing error messages that would get thrown when you reference an undeclared variable.
- I also considered a method where you: Make note of all the keys in `$GLOBALS`, then store a unique value in your target variable (recording it's original value first for later use). And then search `$GLOBALS` looking for that unique value to determine the name of the variable AND (by comparing with your earlier look at `$GLOBALS`) determine if the variable existed before.  But this also seems messy and unreliable.

Answer (score 5):

Using modified example from [PHP - Differenciate an undefined variable from a null variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832119/php-differenciate-an-undefined-variable-from-a-null-variable)

we can differentiate it:

```
$v1 = null;

echo (isset($v1) ? '$v1 set' : '$v1 not set') . PHP_EOL;
echo (is_null($v1) ? '$v1 null' : '$v1 not null') . PHP_EOL;
echo (empty($v1) ? '$v1 empty' : '$v1 not empty') . PHP_EOL;
echo (array_key_exists('v1', get_defined_vars()) ? '$v1 defined' : '$v1 not defined') . PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL;
echo (isset($v2) ? '$v2 set' : '$v2 not set') . PHP_EOL;
echo (@is_null($v2) ? '$v2 null' : '$v2 not null') . PHP_EOL;
echo (empty($v2) ? '$v2 empty' : '$v2 not empty') . PHP_EOL;
echo (array_key_exists('v2', get_defined_vars()) ? '$v2 defined' : '$v2 not defined') . PHP_EOL;
```

prints:

```
$v1 not set
$v1 null
$v1 empty
$v1 defined

$v2 not set
$v2 null
$v2 empty
$v2 not defined
```

we can use `array_key_exists(..., get_defined_vars())` and `is_null(...)` to detect both situations

Comment: `@is_null($v2)` what do you call `@` in php ?, I want to learn more about it. Good answer thou.

Comment: @OmarAbbas `@` sign is just to suppress warning

Answer (score 2):

You can't wrap this kind of logic in a function or method as any variable defined in a function signature will be implicitly "set". Try something like this (contains code smell)

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

try {
    if (null === $var) {
        // null your variable is, hmmm
    }
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    // variable is undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP typically variables that have not been set or that have been unset are considered `null`. The meaning of `null` is "no value". There is a distinct difference between "no value" and a value left blank. For instance, if a user submitted a form with `foo=&bar=baz`, `$_GET['foo']` is set to the value of empty string `""`, which is distinctly different from `null` which would be the value for any key other than `'foo'` and `'bar'`.

That all being said, you *can* find out if a variable was never set or `unset`, although they will *always* evaluate to `true` with `is_null` (`is_null` is the negative of `isset` with the exception that it will throw notices if the value was never set).

One way is if you have the variable in an array of some sort:

```
echo array_key_exists( $variableName, $theArray ) ? 'variable was set, possibly to null' : 'variable was never set';
```

If you need to check a global variable, use the `$GLOBALS` array:

```
echo array_key_exists( $variableName, $GLOBALS ) ? 'variable exists in global scope' : 'this global variable doesn\'t exist';
```

The alternative method I've come up with for figuring out whether the variable was set is a bit more involved, and really unnecessary unless this is a feature that you **absolutely have to have** (in which case you should be able to build it without too much difficulty).

It relies on the fact that `is_null` triggers a notice when a variable hasn't been set. Add an error handler that converts `errors` into `Exceptions`, and use a `try...catch...` block to catch the exception that's thrown and set a flag in the `catch` statement. Just after the `catch` block execute your code that relies on this feature.

It's a dirty-nasty-hack if you ask me, and completely unnecessary, as `null` should be considered the same as an `unset` variable.

Comment: No `finally` in PHP. Also, you're a copy-cat ;)

Comment: @Phil, I didn't read your answers when I wrote this, because they hadn't been posted when I started. The edit was to finish my thought, and when I was done with everything I went through and read what everyone else had written. I agree that we have similar thoughts. Thanks for the `catch` on the `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of the defined variables in the current scope with:

```
get_defined_vars();
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.2 or greater, I guess it is possible as follows:

```
// checking a variable (before and after it is defined)
$var_status1 = @is_defined( $variable, __LINE__, __FILE__ ); // don't put any additional code on this line
$variable = NULL;
$var_status2 = @is_defined( $variable, __LINE__, __FILE__ ); // don't put any additional code on this line

function is_defined( $var, $line, $file ) {
    $e = error_get_last();
    if ( $e !== NULL && $e['type'] === 8 && $e['line'] === $line && $e['file'] === $file  ) {
        return 'Undefined';
    } else {
        return 'Defined';
    }
}

echo $var_status1 . '<br>';
echo $var_status2 . '<br>';
```

Note: I did not have time to test this solution in all possible situations (I just use it in a plugin I developed), so everyone is invited to find a flaw here.

Answer (score -1):

This only works with globally defined variables.  Because of scoping it won't work with local variables in functions or with class properties, but of course it's only one line so you could just copy it into a function.

```
function isNullOrUndefined($variable_name) {
  global $$variable_name;
  if (!isset($$variable_name) || is_null($$variable_name)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

$foo = "foo";
$bar = null;

isNullOrUndefined("foo") //false
isNullOrUndefined("bar") //true
isNullOrUndefined("baz") //true
```

Comment: Nice except that requires me to know the name of the variable at the time of coding, which I won't.

Comment: @Andrew How can you not know the name of a variable? How else are you going to use it?

Comment: @Dan Simon, did you test this? It wont work, as [`isset` and `is_null` are negatives of each other](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Answer (score -1):

what about this?

```
try {
    $undefined_var
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $is_undefined = true;
}
if(empty($is_undefined)){ ... }
```